# Is there a literal notation for an array of symbols?

Tags: ruby, arrays, symbols, syntactic-sugar

I like this literal expression for an array of strings:

```
%w( i can easily create arrays of words )
```

I am wondering if there is a literal to get an array of symbols. I know I can do

```
%w( it is less elegant to create arrays of symbols ).map( &:to_sym )
```

but it would be so wonderful just to use a literal.

Comment: This approach would be nicer than just creating an array of symbols? Or a simple method? Meh.

Comment: in this case, what's even the point to the `%w` notation ?

Comment: IMO an array of symbols is less cluttered than an array of strings already, and generally less common. YMMV.

Comment: <troll>seems that the ruby team agreed with me since ruby 2...</troll>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create array of symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354937/create-array-of-symbols)

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Yes!  This is possible now in Ruby 2.0.0.  One way to write it is:

```
%i{foo bar}  # => [:foo, :bar]
```

You can also use other delimiters, so you could also write `%i(foo bar)` or `%i!foo bar!` for example.

This feature was originally announced here:

http://www.ruby-lang.org/zh_TW/news/2012/11/02/ruby-2-0-0-preview1-released/

It is mentioned in the official documentation of Ruby here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings

Comment: thanks,@MarcelJackwerth already stated it in a comment on the previous accepted answer, but i'll accept yours for posterity.

Comment: Note that as with other modifiers, it is possible to use a range of other delimiters. e.g. `%i[foo bar]`, `%i{foo bar}`, `%i!foo bar!`, `%i%foo bar%`.

Comment: If you'd like highlighting support for this in TextMate or Sublime Text, check out [my modified .tmLanguage file in this gist](https://gist.github.com/kreeger/9584625).

Comment: according to [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), it is advised to use `%i[foo  bar]`

Answer (score 27):

In Ruby 1.x, unfortunately the list of available [%-delimiters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) is limited

```
Modifier    Meaning
%q[ ]       Non-interpolated String (except for \\ \[ and \])
%Q[ ]       Interpolated String (default)
%r[ ]       Interpolated Regexp (flags can appear after the closing delimiter)
%s[ ]       Non-interpolated Symbol
%w[ ]       Non-interpolated Array of words, separated by whitespace
%W[ ]       Interpolated Array of words, separated by whitespace
%x[ ]       Interpolated shell command
```

Comment: too bad... thanks for the link and list, though. did not know `%x`, seems more readable than the backticks notation i use

Comment: well, not so unfortunate for those who can barely keep the existing ones in their heads (that would be me).

Comment: In Ruby 2.0 we will get %i for symbol arrays, see: http://www.ruby-lang.org/zh_TW/news/2012/11/02/ruby-2-0-0-preview1-released/