# Each loop with basic array vs ruby arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I noticed both these methods for creating **each loops in ruby on rails** generate the exact same result.

What is the difference between doing the common array approach `[]` and the other ruby way `%w()`? (by the way, what is the real name for this second approach?)

### Common Array

```
<% ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'].each do |k| %>
    <div class="panel-<%= k %>">Panel <%= k.capitalize %></div>
<% end %>
```

### Ruby

```
<% %w(one two three four five).each do |k| %>
    <div class="panel-<%= k %>">Panel <%= k.capitalize %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `%w` is just a syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: @mudasobwa what does `%w` stand for, are there other kinds of prefixes for arrays?

Comment: there exists some of these shortcodes. for an overview with some explanation look at https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/

Comment: `%w` stands for word array.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings

Comment: *"... methods for creating each loops"* - both loops are identical and unrelated to your question, `[...]` and `%w(...)` are different ways to create an *array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are the same.

You can else try

```
%w[]
```

for creating array of strings.
Consider this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8816954/2926641) for further documentation