# Rails resources routes miss parameters yet match documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails' `resources` directive, I have created a set of routes for a controller (`contacts`). I'm now editing the default views they come with to include some of my own content. However, the `link_to` method is failing, telling me that I'm missing a required parameter.

> No route matches `{:action => 'show', :controller => 'contacts', :id => nil}` missing required keys `[:id]`

It's obvious *why* this is happening - the `link_to` method is not being supplied with an ID, instead it's getting nil. However, the code I'm using matches the documentation for `link_to`.

This is the view in question:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.first %></td>
    <td><%= contact.last %></td>
    <td><%= contact.title %></td>
    <td><%= contact.city %></td>
    <td><%= contact.phone %></td>
    <td><%= contact.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', contact %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', contact.id, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

- `@contacts` is a set of contacts returned from the controller. The line that sets that is:

  ```
  @contacts = Contact.select("title, first, last, city, phone, email")
                     .where("created_by" => @current_user.id)
  ```
- The relevant content of the routes.rb file is simply `resources :contacts`.

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) states:

> Because it relies on url_for, link_to supports both older-style controller/action/id arguments and newer RESTful routes. Current Rails style favors RESTful routes whenever possible, so base your application on resources and use [...]
>
> ```
> link_to "Profile", @profile
> ```

This appears to be what I'm using with `link_to 'Show', contact`.

- Why is the ID not getting passed to `link_to`?
- What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Are you sure that the id value of the contact is filled ? To answer, we would need to know what is in @contacts ? Maybe there is a select clause that prevent from accessing the contact attribute ?

Comment: @Oxynum Edited in, and I think you might be right now that I look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Contact.select("title, first, last, city, phone, email")
```

to

```
Contact.select("title, first, last, city, phone, email, id")
```

the contact's id is nil because it isn't in the select query.

Also, although it doesn't seem to be causing problems right now, I would reccomend using an array of symbols instead of a comma-separated string, so that the sql query is more specific. For example:

```
Contact.select("title, first").to_sql #=> SELECT title, first FROM contacts
Contact.select(:title,:first).to_sql #=> SELECT "contacts"."title", "contacts"."first" FROM contacts
```

This way if you do a join with another model, it won't complain about the unspecific `id` in select. If you feel like you're typing too much, you can use the [%i(...) syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816877/is-there-a-literal-notation-for-an-array-of-symbols):

```
Contact.select(*%i(title first last city phone email))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine.

Maybe you have an instance in the @contacts array that is not saved and therefore, has no id?

Another way to put the same (again, your code is fine) would be:

= link_to 'Show', contact_path(contact)

I would suggest posting the routes file.

Comment: Routes file edited in, though the only relevant part is `resources :contacts`